# Does a '99 Dakota brake lines use a bubble flare or a double flare?

Tags: dodge, dakota, brake-lines

The long brake line from the front to the rear in my '98 Dodge Dakota rotted out and I'm half-way through replacing it.  (The title says '99 Dakota because the brakes are the '99 design.)

I'm pretty sure the 4 ends I've seen of the old brake lines are bubble flares.

**The old lines definitely appear to be factory bent so I would assume they were bubble flared by the factory also.**

All the forums I've checked and **the manual** on alldatadiy.com say **to double flare** the lines.

### Should I double flare or bubble flare the brake lines on a '99 Dakota?

Please note that this matters because the `seats` in the female parts are very different.

Old line:
[image]

Inside of union:
[image]

Comment: That's a bubble flare.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for confirming that.  I still need to know if it is *supposed* to have bubble flares or not.

Comment: take a picture of the female parts either on a hose or at the master cylinder.

Comment: that union is for a bubble flare as well if it were a double inverted there would be a hump around the hole for the flare to sit on. if that's stock it's safe to say that the system uses bubble flares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your truck has bubble flare type terminations, you need to use same same for the replacement. If you don't, you have to know it will leak. It really doesn't matter what the "book" says when what's staring you in the face is the answer. Neither end of the connection (male or female) is double flare.