# How do I choose the correct thermostat?

Tags: audi, thermostat

I want to change the thermostat in my **2001 Audi A3 8L1 1.9L** myself, but I don't know which one to buy. I went on my local dealer's website, punched in my vehicle information, and I got a few thermostat results from different manufacturers. They all have the same temperature info, but vary in size.

Since I don't have any technical specs for my car or anything like that, how would I go about choosing the right one?

Comment: Wow, it is very difficult to find parts for your car online from both US and euro sites.  Do you know the engine code? There were 2 versions of the 1.9 in '01; there were also 2 different versions in '00.  Your choices are: `AGR/ALH`, `ATD/AXR`, `AHF/ASV`, or `ASZ`.

Comment: Yes I know its hard, if it were easy I wouldn't have posted here. ^^ My engine is `ASV`. Could you tell me on which sites you are looking for parts? Maybe there are some good ones that I missed...

Comment: I found that the same thermostats work on all four versions of the engine.  [Here are some thermostats for your car in the UK.](http://www.bestpartstore.co.uk/audi/a3-8l1/15011/10195-thermostat)

Comment: Also, what do you mean they "vary in size"?  Which dimensions vary?

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski The thermostats you posted also vary in size - height specifically. One is 55 and the other is 31 and some do not supply the diemsnions at all. How can I be sure it will fit my car?

Comment: Take your thermostat out and measure it?  Haha.  I bet they both would fit, but you could order both, take your current thermostat out, compare and use the closer sized one, and then return the unused thermostat.    Don't scuff the return part or get it dirty.  I *do not* recommend solely relying on words on the internet; [what's really in the car is often different than what the manual says.](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/35259/10831) I return probably 40% of the parts I buy because my vehicles are Frankensteins!

Answer (score 4):

Go to a site for parts diagrams with a VIN/chassis number lookup like http://www.realoem.me. Give it a try, I think it will be quite helpful.

Using that site based on an ASV engine I believe you need 044121113

Comment: Yes I also think the part number `044121113` is correct. I visited the website you posted (very good website) punched in this code, clicked on `Buy` and ended up on [FCPEuro website](https://www.fcpeuro.com/products?keywords=044121113), chose the [Genuine part](https://www.fcpeuro.com/products/audi-vw-engine-coolant-thermostat-vag-044121113), chose Fitment tab and guess what, my model **IS NOT** listed. This is what bugs me! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

@FCPEuro neat website

What I always look for is:

- is it in the correct temp range for your car
- is it a high flow thermostat?

you need the proper temperature so the engine will run correctly without getting too hot or cold.

A high flow thermostat can relieve some problems with extra hot days.